# Обновление EditText через кастомный ListView

Tags: android

Имеется `EditText` и `ListView`. У `ListView` каждый `item` имеет 2 кнопки. Необходимо по нажатию кнопок отображать какой-либо текст в `EditText`. Какие могут быть варианты решения задачи?

Answer (score 1):

В адаптере у `ListView` на кнопки повесить `setOnClickListener()` и по клику `mEditText.setText("текст")`.

Comment: Пробовал, этот вариант не работает, почему то не обновляет текст. Пришлось в главной активити реализовать метод изменяющий edittext, и вызывать его в адаптере. Криво, но работает.

Comment: @SergioVM05 Что-то вы не так сделали, раз не заработало